# getting result from JSON in iphone SDK with strange character and numbers

Tags: iphone, json

i am developing an iphone app that receive data from sql server through php file in JSON format , it work fine when test it on safari browser, also i used SBJSON framework
to develop the JSON in my app ,i received the data in my app but in wrong format like this :

```
["&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b;&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b; &#x0639;&#x0634;&#x0631; - &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0645;&#x0624;&#x0642;&#x062a; - UIDatePicker ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b;&#x0627;&#x0645;&#x0646; - &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x0646;&#x062a;&#x0642;&#x0627;&#x0644; &#x0645;&#x0646; &#x0635;&#x0641;&#x062d;&#x0647; &#x0644;&#x0627;&#x062e;&#x0631;&#x0649; - UISwipeGestureRecognizer","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x0648;&#x0644; - &#x0645;&#x0642;&#x062f;&#x0645;&#x0629; &#x0644;&#x062a;&#x0637;&#x0648;&#x064a;&#x0631; &#x062a;&#x0637;&#x0628;&#x064a;&#x0642;&#x0627;&#x062a; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x064a;&#x0641;&#x0648;&#x0646; - introduction to Xcode ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b;&#x0627;&#x0646;&#x064a; - &#x0625;&#x0646;&#x0634;&#x0627;&#x0621; &#x0623;&#x0648;&#x0644; &#x062a;&#x0637;&#x0628;&#x064a;&#x0642; &#x0639;&#x0644;&#x0649; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x064a;&#x0641;&#x0648;&#x0646; - create your frst app in iphone ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b;&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b; - &#x0627;&#x0633;&#x062a;&#x062e;&#x062f;&#x0627;&#x0645; &#x062d;&#x0642;&#x0644; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0645;&#x062f;&#x062e;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x062a; - Using of JTextField in Xcode ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0631;&#x0627;&#x0628;&#x0639; - &#x0627;&#x0633;&#x062a;&#x062e;&#x062f;&#x0627;&#x0645; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0639;&#x062f;&#x0627;&#x062f; &#x0641;&#x064a; &#x0628;&#x0631;&#x0645;&#x062c;&#x0629; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x064a;&#x0641;&#x0648;&#x0646; - Using UIslider and UIstepper ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062e;&#x0627;&#x0645;&#x0633; - &#x0627;&#x0633;&#x062a;&#x062e;&#x062f;&#x0627;&#x0645; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0635;&#x0648;&#x0631;&#x0629; &#x0648; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0633;&#x0648;&#x064a;&#x062a;&#x0634; - Using UISwitch and UIImageView ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0633;&#x0627;&#x062f;&#x0633; - &#x0639;&#x0645;&#x0644; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0647; &#x062d;&#x0627;&#x0633;&#x0628;&#x0629; &#x0644;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x064a;&#x0641;&#x0648;&#x0646; &#x062c;&#x0661; - Create Calculator for iPhone part 1 ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0633;&#x0627;&#x062f;&#x0633; - Create Calculator for iPhone part 2 - &#x0639;&#x0645;&#x0644; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0647; &#x062d;&#x0627;&#x0633;&#x0628;&#x0647; &#x0644;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x064a;&#x0641;&#x0648;&#x0646; &#x062c;&#x0662; ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0633;&#x0627;&#x0628;&#x0639; - &#x0639;&#x0631;&#x0636; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0645;&#x0644;&#x0641;&#x0627;&#x062a; &#x0639;&#x0644;&#x0649; &#x0635;&#x0641;&#x062d;&#x0629; &#x0648;&#x064a;&#x0628; - Loading PDF,PPT on UIWebview ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062a;&#x0627;&#x0633;&#x0639; - &#x0645;&#x062a;&#x0635;&#x0641;&#x062d; &#x0627;&#x0646;&#x062a;&#x0631;&#x0646;&#x062a; &#x0644;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x064a;&#x0641;&#x0648;&#x0646; - web browser for iphone ","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b;&#x0627;&#x0645;&#x0646; - &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x0646;&#x062a;&#x0642;&#x0627;&#x0644; &#x0645;&#x0646; &#x0635;&#x0641;&#x062d;&#x0647; &#x0644;&#x0627;&#x062e;&#x0631;&#x0649; - UISwipeGestureRecognizer","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0639;&#x0627;&#x0634;&#x0631; - &#x0645;&#x063a;&#x0651;&#x064a;&#x0631; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0642;&#x064a;&#x0645; - UISegmentedControl","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062d;&#x0627;&#x062f;&#x064a; &#x0639;&#x0634;&#x0631; - &#x062e;&#x0644;&#x0627;&#x064a;&#x0627; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062c;&#x062f;&#x0627;&#x0648;&#x0644; - uitableviewcell & uinavigationcontroller","&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b;&#x0627;&#x0646;&#x064a; &#x0639;&#x0634;&#x0631; -&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062a;&#x0627;&#x0628; &#x0628;&#x0627;&#x0631; - UITabBarController"]
```

the other problem when i try to parse it , it gives me null result

```
  NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/newjson.php"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
listt = [parser objectWithString:url];
```

listt (NSArray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by passing an `NSError *` to your URL fetch function to look for an error.

The JSON you posted is valid (though the strings appear to be HTML-encoded for some reason). What happens if you NSLog the value of `listt`? The value of `url`?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",url);
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

it is gonna be ok bro</br>["&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062f;&#x0631;&#x0633; &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b;&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x062b; (many thing like that but i removed it because of comment letters limitation)

Comment: Your problem is all the HTML; you have to prevent your php script from printing all of that stuff that shows up before the opening "[" character. Maybe post your php script?

Comment: no sir , it works fine in php script and i am getting the right result in the browser when i tested it ..

Comment: i faced this problem in the php script before, but i solved it their ,it was unicode problem.

Comment: If you view-source of the page, it needs to include only the JSON text starting with "["; not the "it is gonna be ok bro" or other tags.

Comment: function json_encode_ar($rows){
$str= json_encode($rows) ;
$converted = preg_replace('/\\\u([0-9a-z]{4})/i', '&#x$1;', $str);
$new_string = stripslashes($converted);
return $new_string ; 
}

$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$totalRows_r = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($totalRows_r > 0){
do { 
$rows[]= $r['post_title'];

} while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result));
echo json_encode_ar($rows) ;

}else{
echo " no result";

}

Comment: You should remove all HTML code outside your `<?php` tags and all "echo" statements other than the one that outputs the JSON. The data you send back to the browser has to be *just* the JSON.

Comment: i did everything you said, but the same problem, getting strange character and numbers